# Filter List of labels

Tags: java

I have a list of labels which I want to filter and leave only labels `"low"  "lowest"  "high"`

I tried to implement this:

```
private List<Label> filterPriorityLabels(List<Label> labels)
    {
        for (ListIterator<Label> iter = labels.listIterator(); iter.hasNext();)
        {
            Label a = iter.next();
            if (a.getName() != "low" | "lowest" | "high")
            {
                iter.remove();
            }
        }

        return labels;
    }
```

But I can't get the working example. How I can fix this code?

Comment: `if (a.getName() != "low" | "lowest" | "high")` is probably supposed to be `if (a.getName() != "low" && a.getName() != "lowest" && a.getName() != "high")`

Comment: This code is so wrong that I'm wondering if you've ever learned the basics of Java?

Comment: @domdom - The number of `;` in the `for` loop head is just the right number.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw you're right, good point. Then again, I just wanted to point out the absolute fundamental misconception of the condition's logic (`|` instead of `&&` and so on)

Comment: Ah, dammit, all my comments turn out to be rubbish today. Thanks for pointing out my mistakes @TedHopp

Comment: @domdom alright , i see. all good :).

Comment: The usual "that's not how to compare Strings", but even more critically, that's not how Java if blocks work suggesting that your best answer is to first and foremost study some basic Java tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete example based on [the answer by @davidxxx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43438807/535871):

```
private static final List<String> acceptableNames =
    Arrays.asList("low", "lowest", "high");

private List<Label> filterPriorityLabels(List<Label> labels)
{
    for (ListIterator<Label> iter = labels.listIterator(); iter.hasNext();)
    {
        final Label a = iter.next();
        if (!acceptableNames.contains(a.getName())
        {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }

    return labels;
}
```

If you're using Java 8, there's a nicer way using streams:

```
private static final List<String> acceptableNames =
    Arrays.asList("low", "lowest", "high");

private List<Label> filterPriorityLabels(List<Label> labels)
{
    return labels.stream()
                 .filter( p -> acceptableNames.contains(p.getName()) )
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Note, though, that unlike davidxxx's answer, this does not modify the original list and return it. Instead, it leaves the original list unchanged and returns a new list.

Comment: I love the Dijkstra quote on your profile. True and very well said :)

Comment: @davidxxx - Thanks. He has lots of good quotes, but I think that one is one of his best. :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't compare String with `!=` but `!equals()`.
And a finer solution would be to use `contains()` method of List.

```
 List<String> acceptableNames = Arrays.asList("low","lowest","high");
 if (!acceptableNames.contains(a.getName()))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (! (a.getName().equals("low") || a.getName().equals("lowest") || a.getName().equals("high")))
```

- in Java, you compare Strings (and objects in general), with `equals()`, not ==
- the `or` logical operator is `||`, not `|`
- it expects several boolean expressions as operands. Not Strings.

Also, the signature of your method leads to think that the method creates another list, containing the filtered elements of the original list, whereas it actually modifies the list passed as argument. It should return void, or create and return a copy.